# Change style.fontWeight of Joomla! Articles Category Module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component, joomla-module

I am setting up a feed that lists articles modified in the last 30 days.  However, I would like this list to be of `fontWeight:normal`.  The options within Joomla! only allow for heading style.  I have access to the `*.php` files if necessary.

I have tried modifying the `mod_articles_category.php` already and was able to change everything **but** what I wanted.

I know one way is to trick the module by having a blank `Month and Year` Group, but then the list is tabbed over and the text is bunched up.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thank you.

**SOLVED**:
Solved this by modifying the `mod_articles_category.xml`.  I changed the `value` of `JH6` to `value="0"`.

**EDIT:**
I asked/wrote this question and its "solution" very early in my developing career.  **DO NOT** do what I did.  The correct method would be to alter the CSS as explained in the comments.

Comment: The problem with that is that it will get wiped out on an updata potentially.  Better to make a layout override and put it in the html/modules folder of your template.

Comment: Styling is done with CSS. Don't mess with the PHP code.

Comment: Even if I would have made a CSS, the problem was that the conversion from the XML to the style was hardcoded.  This wasn't a separate extension, it was one of the core features of Joomla!.  I would have had to hack several files to get a style change to push through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by modifying the `mod_articles_category.xml`.  I changed the `value` of `JH6` to `value="0"`.

**EDIT:**
Do not use this answer, please see my **EDIT** at the end of my original question.